# How to parse the Json data when there are no nodes before JSONArray? (Android)

Tags: android, json

```
[
-{
body: "Deloitte experts believe that Expo 2020 Dubai will be a major “game changer for Dubai” whereby it will create significant changes — whether opportunities or challenges — in most industries and market sectors that could spill over to other countries in the region. “It is clear that Expo 2020 will go beyond a local showcase of commerce, technology and infrastructure, however impressive these things may be,” said Mutasem Dajani, Deloitte UAE regional managing partner. He adds: “Dubai will itself become an agent for future global progress as securing sustainable energy and resources, connecting and moving people, goods and services across markets and exploring the intrinsic spirit of entrepreneurship come together in a location that is uniquely synonymous with achievement in each of these areas.” Humphry Hatton, CEO of Deloitte Corporate Finance Limited (DCFL) regulated by the DIFC, addresses international investments in the region and adds that hosting Expo 2020 in Dubai will “further the attractiveness of Dubai as a base for overseas companies wishing to invest in the Middle East.” Anis Sadek, Dubai managing partner at Deloitte points out that, “It only takes a quick analysis of the impact of an expected additional 20 million international visitors over a six-month period to see that significant investment in hospitality and retail infrastructure will be required.” Rashid Bashir, head of the strategy practice at Deloitte Middle East cautions that “it would be beneficial to develop a dedicated legacy plan to ensure that the event’s potential as a catalyst to transform Dubai’s economy is maximized”. Their views are grouped in the report “Expo 2020: A game changer for Dubai”, and “Countdown to FATCA” available in the spring 2014 issue of the Deloitte Middle East Point of View (ME PoV) publication which also includes the views of other Deloitte partners and industry experts Cynthia Corby, Akbar Ahmad and Jesdev Saggar on the impact of Expo 2022 in the construction, financial services, and infrastructure and capital industries."
created_at: "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z"
date_time: "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z"
department: "Finance"
id: 291
include: true
mediaType: "Domestic Social Media"
priority: "1"
title: "Expo 2020 game will be changer for Dubai"
updated_at: "2014-04-22T08:18:34Z"
user_id: 2
},
-{
body: "Dubai: Dubai’s foreign trade is expected to touch Dh4 trillion by hosting Expo 2020, Mahmoud Al Bastaki, CEO of Dubai Trade, said on day two of the Annual Investment Meeting 2014 in Dubai. “While all business sectors will be growing drastically from now until the hosting of Expo 2020, trade will get the highest leap among all businesses in the UAE,” he said during plenary session at AIM entitle Expo 2020, unlocking new opportunities for potential partnerships in the UAE and the region. In 2013, Dubai trade hit Dh1.392 trillion and was the major contributors to Dubai’s GDP with almost 30 per cent of the total. Ahead of Expo 2020, the government will keep spending on infrastructure, prompting more businesses and investment will come to the UAE. New projects to be developed across all business sectors, and demand on goods will be drastically increase. All these factors will energise the trade market overall, Al Bastaki said. He also added that Expo 2020 will facilitate economic diversification by finding new paths for economic developments. “One of these paths is the development of the physical and social infrastructure, innovation centers and partnership projects.” In line with hosting this big event, the real estate market will witness great developments especially in the area around the Expo site and Dubai World Central. “This alone will boost most of the relevant sectors including wholesale trade, transport and logistics, communications and business services,” The development of other manufacturing industries, cement, construction materials will take part in this boost. Highlighting economic sectors growth and development prior Expo 2020 and how it will go during and after this event, Khalifa Al Zaffin, Executive Chairman of Dubai Aviation City Corporation, in line with Expo 2020 opportunities to capitalise on thriving sector. “In anticipation of the upcoming Expo, Dubai World Central (DWC) has witnessed an increase in land value and development activity which means a potential for attracting new investments,’ Al Zaffin said. “And over the coming years we expect to see a surge in both commercial and residential investments which definitely will be stimulating the small and medium enterprises (SMEs) as well as services sector,” he added. During Expo 2020, Al Zaffin portray how DWC will be a unique business and residential community district during expo. “DWC will include all facilities for businesses, residents and visitors. There will be districts for logistic, business, commercial, residential, exhibitions, hospitality, humanitarian and entertainment.” All these will be developed by attracted a lot of local and foreign investors, and will be resulting in natural growth of Gross Domestic Production (GDP) during and after Expo 2020, he added. Infrastructure UAE and Dubai is going to invest heavily on infrastructure ahead of Expo 2020, said Khalid Al Malek, CEO Group of Dubai Properties Group, during the plenary session. He also expected this to enhance growth in other relative sectors, including real estate and construction. According to the latest statistic last year, Al Malek said, construction and infrastructure projects announced and underway in the Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) countries accounts for $1.9 trillion while UAE’s shares accounts for 49 per cent of the overall projects. “UAE continues to remain the largest projects market, with around $940 billion project that have been under execution,” he added. Projects in the UAE are dominated by infrastructure and construction, as several large projects that were earlier deferred or delayed have been revived, he said. Sizeable investment in utilities is taking place as well, given the ambitious long-term growth plans, according to him. Al Malek described the overall investment climate as a conducive with well established infrastructure and connectivity with the rest of the world. This is one of the advantage that Dubai enjoys to attract investments. Adding to this, he remarked that significant availability of low cost natural resources, consistent GDP growth and generation of surplus, high positioning in transparency and competitiveness index, re-export hub, developed free zones and strategic location are Dubai’s economic strength, Al Malek said."
created_at: "2014-04-15T10:19:07Z"
date_time: "2014-04-15T10:19:07Z"
department: "Finance"
id: 247
include: true
mediaType: "International Established"
priority: "1"
title: "Dubai Expo 2020 to produce Dh4 trillion foreign trade"
updated_at: "2014-04-15T10:19:16Z"
user_id: 2
}]
```

The above is my **complete** json data. I bought the json data successfully to my logcat by writing below code.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error" + statusCode,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
String jsonData = stringBuilder.toString();
//To display json data in LOGCAT
Log.d("Latest 20 feeds", jsonData);
```

My question is how can i parse the data and display in logcat, ex: all the "title", "body" etc.

Comment: yes it is valid, i checked in postman.

Comment: check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The json data is having errors.

Comment: probably the jason is not valid, there are syntax errors

Comment: @Raghunandan, you are right json is not valid in in jsonlint.com but it is displaying results in POSTMAN. Is there any other way of getting data which is valid in postman? Can you suggest me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, you have invalid `JSON` data. I don't know how did you check and found that valid but I found a lot of `errors` and you can check that too by pasting it here [JSON Validate](http://json.parser.online.fr/)
I have removed some of your `STRING` data to make it fit well in the space and removed `errors`, so how it looks like is here

```
[
{
"body": "Deloitte experts believe that Expo 2020 Dubai will and infrastructure and capital industries.",
"created_at": "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z",
"date_time": "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z",
"department": "Finance",
"id": 291,
"include": true,
"mediaType": "Domestic Social Media",
"priority": "1",
"title": "Expo 2020 game will be changer for Dubai",
"updated_at": "2014-04-22T08:18:34Z",
"user_id": 2
},
{
"body": "Dubai: Dubai’s foreign trade is expected to, Al Malek said.",
"created_at": "2014-04-15T10:19:07Z",
"date_time": "2014-04-15T10:19:07Z",
"department": "Finance",
"id": 247,
"include": true,
"mediaType": "International Established",
"priority": "1",
"title": "Dubai Expo 2020 to produce Dh4 trillion foreign trade",
"updated_at": "2014-04-15T10:19:16Z",
"user_id": 2
}
]
```

and it's in valid format now, so all you need now to do is...

```
JSONAarray array = new JSONArray(JsonString);
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = object.getString("title");
    String body = object.getString("body");
    System.out.println("Titlte: " + title);
    System.out.println("Body: " + body);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate JSON Dynamically this way

**Create these Methods**

1)

```
public void parseJson(JSONArray data) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("data", data);

            parseJson(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2)

```
    private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();

                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(key + " : " + data.getString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(key + " : " + data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**How to Use?**

```
String jsonData = stringBuilder.toString();
        try {
            parseJson(new JSONArray(jsonData));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that the json string you get is valid. When it a valid JSON, by using the JSONArray constructor provided with the `jsonData` string you would get a JSONArray of your json objects. here is a full example:

```
jsonData = "{" + jsonData + "}";
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);
```

I hope you are using [this](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list) JSON library.

From my investigation it is not valid (missing semi columns and more). You can use [this](http://jsonlint.com/) tool to validate your json.

Here is a valid json string:

```
[
    {
        "body": "Deloitte experts believe that Expo 2020 Dubai will be a major “game changer for Dubai” whereby it will create significant changes — whether opportunities or challenges — in most industries and market sectors that could spill over to other countries in the region. “It is clear that Expo 2020 will go beyond a local showcase of commerce, technology and infrastructure, however impressive these things may be,” said Mutasem Dajani, Deloitte UAE regional managing partner. He adds: “Dubai will itself become an agent for future global progress as securing sustainable energy and resources, connecting and moving people, goods and services across markets and exploring the intrinsic spirit of entrepreneurship come together in a location that is uniquely synonymous with achievement in each of these areas.” Humphry Hatton, CEO of Deloitte Corporate Finance Limited (DCFL) regulated by the DIFC, addresses international investments in the region and adds that hosting Expo 2020 in Dubai will “further the attractiveness of Dubai as a base for overseas companies wishing to invest in the Middle East.” Anis Sadek, Dubai managing partner at Deloitte points out that, “It only takes a quick analysis of the impact of an expected additional 20 million international visitors over a six-month period to see that significant investment in hospitality and retail infrastructure will be required.” Rashid Bashir, head of the strategy practice at Deloitte Middle East cautions that “it would be beneficial to develop a dedicated legacy plan to ensure that the event’s potential as a catalyst to transform Dubai’s economy is maximized”. Their views are grouped in the report “Expo 2020: A game changer for Dubai”, and “Countdown to FATCA” available in the spring 2014 issue of the Deloitte Middle East Point of View (ME PoV) publication which also includes the views of other Deloitte partners and industry experts Cynthia Corby, Akbar Ahmad and Jesdev Saggar on the impact of Expo 2022 in the construction, financial services, and infrastructure and capital industries.",
        "created_at": "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z",
        "date_time": "2014-04-22T08:18:14Z",
        "department": "Finance",
        "id": 291,
        "include": true,
        "mediaType": "Domestic Social Media",
        "priority": 1,
        "title": "Expo 2020 game will be changer for Dubai",
        "updated_at": "2014-04-22T08:18:34Z",
        "user_id": 2
    },
    {
        "body": "Dubai: Dubai’s foreign trade is expected to touch Dh4 trillion by hosting Expo 2020, Mahmoud Al Bastaki, CEO of Dubai Trade, said on day two of the Annual Investment Meeting 2014 in Dubai. “While all business sectors will be growing drastically from now until the hosting of Expo 2020, trade will get the highest leap among all businesses in the UAE,” he said during plenary session at AIM entitle Expo 2020, unlocking new opportunities for potential partnerships in the UAE and the region. In 2013, Dubai trade hit Dh1.392 trillion and was the major contributors to Dubai’s GDP with almost 30 per cent of the total. Ahead of Expo 2020, the government will keep spending on infrastructure, prompting more businesses and investment will come to the UAE. New projects to be developed across all business sectors, and demand on goods will be drastically increase. All these factors will energise the trade market overall, Al Bastaki said. He also added that Expo 2020 will facilitate economic diversification by finding new paths for economic developments. “One of these paths is the development of the physical and social infrastructure, innovation centers and partnership projects.” In line with hosting this big event, the real estate market will witness great developments especially in the area around the Expo site and Dubai World Central. “This alone will boost most of the relevant sectors including wholesale trade, transport and logistics, communications and business services,” The development of other manufacturing industries, cement, construction materials will take part in this boost. Highlighting economic sectors growth and development prior Expo 2020 and how it will go during and after this event, Khalifa Al Zaffin, Executive Chairman of Dubai Aviation City Corporation, in line with Expo 2020 opportunities to capitalise on thriving sector. “In anticipation of the upcoming Expo, Dubai World Central (DWC) has witnessed an increase in land value and development activity which means a potential for attracting new investments,’ Al Zaffin said. “And over the coming years we expect to see a surge in both commercial and residential investments which definitely will be stimulating the small and medium enterprises (SMEs) as well as services sector,” he added. During Expo 2020, Al Zaffin portray how DWC will be a unique business and residential community district during expo. “DWC will include all facilities for businesses, residents and visitors. There will be districts for logistic, business, commercial, residential, exhibitions, hospitality, humanitarian and entertainment.” All these will be developed by attracted a lot of local and foreign investors, and will be resulting in natural growth of Gross Domestic Production (GDP) during and after Expo 2020, he added. Infrastructure UAE and Dubai is going to invest heavily on infrastructure ahead of Expo 2020, said Khalid Al Malek, CEO Group of Dubai Properties Group, during the plenary session. He also expected this to enhance growth in other relative sectors, including real estate and construction. According to the latest statistic last year, Al Malek said, construction and infrastructure projects announced and underway in the Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) countries accounts for $1.9 trillion while UAE’s shares accounts for 49 per cent of the overall projects. “UAE continues to remain the largest projects market, with around $940 billion project that have been under execution,” he added. Projects in the UAE are dominated by infrastructure and construction, as several large projects that were earlier deferred or delayed have been revived, he said. Sizeable investment in utilities is taking place as well, given the ambitious long-term growth plans, according to him. Al Malek described the overall investment climate as a conducive with well established infrastructure and connectivity with the rest of the world. This is one of the advantage that Dubai enjoys to attract investments. Adding to this, he remarked that significant availability of low cost natural resources, consistent GDP growth and generation of surplus, high positioning in transparency and competitiveness index, re-export hub, developed free zones and strategic location are Dubai’s economic strength, Al Malek said.",
        "created_at": "2014-04-15T10: 19: 07Z",
        "date_time": "2014-04-15T10: 19: 07Z",
        "department": "Finance",
        "id": 247,
        "include": true,
        "mediaType": "InternationalEstablished",
        "priority": 1,
        "title": "DubaiExpo2020toproduceDh4trillionforeigntrade",
        "updated_at": "2014-04-15T10: 19: 16Z",
        "user_id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: @shiva, take a look at the valid json in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example JSONArray. So you can parse it to Array of objects. Simple way is using Gson:

```
String jsonData = stringBuilder.toString();
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyDataObject [] data = gson.fromJson(jsonData, MyDataObject[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) lib for auto parsing (just download latest version of GSON jar file and put it to your project inside libs folder):

1) Create class describing your data model

```
    public class SomeObjectClass {
        @SerializedName("body")
        private String mBody;

        @SerializedName("created_at")
        private String mCreatedAt;

        @SerializedName("date_time")
        private String mDateTime;

        @SerializedName("department")
        private String mDepartment;

        @SerializedName("id")
        private long mId;

        @SerializedName("include")
        private boolean mInclude;

        // another fields here

        // some getters if you need it
    }
```

2) Create method for parsing your json string to list of your objects

```
    public List<SomeObjectClass> parseJson(String jsonArray) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SomeObjectClass>>() {}.getType();
        List<SomeObjectClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
        return yourClassList;
    }
```

3) Parse your json

```
List<SomeObjectClass> objects = parseJson(jsonData);
```

4) Iterate it and log